# solution for large contingency table

Tags: spss, contingency-tables

I have performed logistic regression using SPSS on my data with a dichotomous variable as the dependent variable with three independent variables and three covariates (they are mostly categorical)

The problem is that my sample size is really small (88). The categorical variable has two or three categories within in, so it results in a huge contingency table.. I have tried to combine categories together, but the contingency table is still huge.. How do I know if I have enough sample to fill all the cells? What can I do differently to overcome this problem?

Comment: How do independent variables and covariates differ?

Comment: Can you give us more details of the problem? What is the predictors, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not see exactly from your question how "huge" your table is and what the problem is.

However, to test for independence you are advised to use an exact test that works for small sample sizes. Usually the recommendation is to use an Chi Squared test only if the expected cell frequency is larger than 5 for each cell. However, a (Fisher's) exact test may be superior even for larger sample sizes than that, see for instance [here](http://www.biostathandbook.com/small.html).